# Arrays- Subscript Out of range Error- Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to coding in Access VBA. I am trying to run the following code to extract the selected records from an Access Table and export them to excel but it keeps on showing me the 'Subscript out of range' error.This is the part of the code where I am getting an error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Tablename", dbOpenDynaset)


Dim k As Integer
Dim n() As Variant
Dim m() As Variant
Dim p() As Variant
Dim q() As Variant
Dim size As Integer
k = 10
i = 1
If Not rec.EOF Then
rec.MoveFirst
rec.FindFirst ("Variable1 = '" & Me.Variable1.Value & "' AND Variable2 = " &       Me.Variable2.Value & " AND Variable3 = '" & Me.Variable3.Value & "'")
size = DCount("[Field4]", "Tablename", "Variable1 = '" & Me.Variable1.Value & "' AND Variable2 = " & Me.Variable2.Value & " AND Variable3 = '" & Me.Variable3.Value & "'")
ReDim n(size) As String
ReDim m(size) As String
ReDim p(size) As String
ReDim q(size) As String

Do Until rec.EOF



If Not IsNull(rec.Fields("Field4")) Then
n(i) = rec.Fields("Field4")
WKS.Cells((k), 1) = n(i)
End If

If Not IsNull(rec.Fields("Field3")) Then
m(i) = rec.Fields("Field3")
WKS.Cells((k), 2) = m(i)
End If

If Not IsNull(rec.Fields("Field2")) Then
p(i) = rec.Fields("Field2")
WKS.Cells((k), 3) = p(i)
End If

If Not IsNull(rec.Fields("Field1")) Then
q(i) = rec.Fields("Field1")
WKS.Cells((k), 4) = q(i)
End If

rec.MoveNext
    k = k + 1
    i = i + 1

Loop
End If
Set rec = Nothing
```

Comment: How is `size` found? and what is the value of it when the code stops?

Comment: i and k start at what value?

Comment: Size is the variable which saves the 'number of records' in which value of field 1 is variable 1 as input by user and so on. When the code stops, it is equal to the number of records which satisfy the condition of equality

Comment: i starts at 1 and k at 10

Comment: Are you going to do something with the array latter?  I see you assign a value then imideately put that value into a cell.  If you are not doing something with the array skip it and put the value directly into the cell.

Comment: Okay I will try that and get back to you. Thank you for the help .

Comment: No, if I do that, all the records are being exported to excel, not the selected ones.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Changing 'Do Until rec.EOF' to 'Do Until i = (size +1)' resolved the issue